# Azure data factory How to catch any error on any activity and log it into database?

Tags: error-handling, azure-data-factory

I am currently working on error handling in ADF.
[image]

I know how to get error from a particular activity by using @ activity('').error.message and then pass it to database.

Do you guys know a generic way that able us to catch any error on any activity on a pipeline?

Best regards!

Comment: Can you please give an example of what you mean by a generic way to catch any error on any activity?

Comment: Hi for example There are many diff activities in one pipeline, does ADF have any function that able to catch any error from those different activities rather than just from one activity as above(Copy source files)

Comment: Hey, The below blog explains the same https://datasharkx.wordpress.com/2021/08/19/error-logging-and-the-art-of-avoiding-redundant-activities-in-azure-data-factory/

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage the flow path dependency aspect within Azure data factory to manage logging of error based on single activity rather than duplicating same activities :
[image]

My blog : https://datasharkx.wordpress.com/2021/08/19/error-logging-and-the-art-of-avoiding-redundant-activities-in-azure-data-factory/ explains all the same in details

Below are the basic principles that need to be followed :

Multiple dependencies with the same source are OR’ed together.
Multiple dependencies with different sources are AND’ed together.
Together this looks like (Act_3fails OR Act_3Skipped) AND (Act_2Completes OR Act_2skipped)

Answer (score 0):

When you have certain number of activities in `pipeline1`, and you want to capture any error message when one of the activities fail, then using `execute pipeline` activity is the correct approach.

- When you use execute pipeline activity to trigger `pipeline1`, when any activity inside pipeline1 fails, it throws an error message which includes the name of the activity which failed.
- Look at the following demonstration. I have a pipeline named `p1` which has 3 activities `get metadata, for each and Script`.

[image]

- I am triggering `p1` pipeline in `p2` pipeline using **execute pipeline activity** and storing the error message in a variable using `set variable` activity. For demonstration, I made sure each activity throws an error each time (3 times).
- When the get metadata activity fails, the respective error message captured in `p2` pipeline will be as follows:

```
Operation on target Get Metadata1 failed: The required Blob is missing. ContainerName: data2, path: data2/files/.
```

[image]

- When only `for each activity` in p1 pipeline fails, the respective error message will be captured in `p2` pipeline.

```
Operation on target ForEach1 failed: Activity failed because an inner activity failed
```

[image]

- When only `script activity` in p1 pipeline fails, the respective error message will be captured in `p2` pipeline.

```
Operation on target Script1 failed: Invalid object name 'mydemotable'
```

[image]

So, using `Execute pipeline` activity (to execute pipeline1) would help you to capture the error message from any different activities that fail inside the required pipeline.